# Slang or idiom for someone who wants to gain weight or bulk up

Tags: idioms, slang, colloquialisms, synonyms

What is a more colourful way of saying someone who wants to gain weight, increase their muscle size by going to the gym?

> He has been regularly visiting the gym in hopes of ___

Can I say ‘packing some guns’ here?

Comment: Getting ripped, developing your abs, pumping up, et al.

Comment: Or *bulking up*.

Comment: Don't say "packing some guns"- that's what you say when describing someone who already is.

Answer (score 3):

*Getting [ripped](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ripped)*.

Which means getting

> Well defined muscles

It also doubles up as getting drunk.

Comment: Getting ripped isn’t the same as bulking up.

Comment: @Jim not identical, but both work well in the OP's context.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you may be asking about one (or possibly both) of the following:

1. "... in hopes of [polite word/phrase for reducing gained fat] ..."
2. "... in hopes of [polite word/phrase for muscle building] ..."

From how I interpret your question I am going to choose to address number 2. For number two I think it's pretty standard to say:

**building up muscle**

So...

> Has been regularly visiting the gym in hopes of building up muscle.

Answer (score 0):

Consider,

***beef up***

> To become bigger, stronger, or bulkier: *The actor beefed up over a couple of months so that he could play the part of a boxer.*
>
> (The American Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs)

***pack on size***

> [Google](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22pack+on+meat%22+meaning&biw=584&bih=383&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj30Z6d0dvLAhUE6RQKHW85ASAQ_AUIBygA&dpr=2#q=%22pack+on+size%22)
>
> *There are millions of guys - commonly known as "hardgainers" or "ectomorphs" - who will never, ever [pack on size](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Ic8QAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=%22pack+on+size%22&source=bl&ots=s7cPrIpNkD&sig=5r8pH6Nc8I5eH1K-vKLelutAT4M&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBtoKC0tvLAhWCXRoKHaXWBmc4HhDoAQgbMAE#v=onepage&q=%22pack%20on%20size%22&f=false).*

***pack on meat***

> [Google](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22pack+on+meat%22+meaning&biw=1024&bih=672&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigtK7vzNvLAhUHXBoKHYI2DF8Q_AUIBygA&dpr=2)

Comment: These seem to be more idiomatic expressions 1. [**"pack on weight"**](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22pack+on+weight%22++bodybuilding) and 2. [**"pack on mass"**](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22pack+on+mass%22++bodybuilding)

Comment: The "pack on meat" has only 9 results in the link.

Answer (score -1):

How about the word "jacked" ???

It seems to me, that compared to the to the other choices, "Jacked" sounds the must hip and evocative. I would imagine a magazine writer, writing an article and needing such a word, would opt to pick this word over the other choices posted (so far.)

Comment: Please support your answer, (and fix your typos :)) the meaning of ["jack off"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jack_off) is quite different , and I'm not sure "jacked" is used in the context described by the OP